# CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a header at the top that holds the following CSS rule:

```css
position: fixed;
```

I also have some images that hold (and need to hold) the following CSS rule:

```css
position: relative;
```

The problem is that my header always sits at the top of the page as the user scrolls, but when they get to the image (with `position: relative`) this sits on top of my header. But the header should always be on top. Is there another CSS rule I can apply to allow this to happen?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It helps to establish context, as I am suspecting that the issue arises due to [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: That problem might be with z-index give ur header z-index:999999999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem might be with `z-index`. Give your header `z-index:999999999` and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just set in CSS `z-index: 9999` to the header `div`.

Answer (score 1):

In your header CSS add `z-index` property:

with:

```css
z-index:10 // can be any number but should be greater than the z-index of image
```

in image CSS add:

```css
z-index:5; //should be less than the z-index of header
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set position as `relative` or `absolute`. You can use the following code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Document Edit</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1500px;
    background-color: #DDD;
  }
  
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #004080;
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .imgdiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="imgdiv"><img src="error1.png" width="400" height="400"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```